# ImportError: cannot import name 'mesh'

Tags: module, pycharm, importerror, mesh

I am trying to create and save an stl file with a cube and I cannot import the mesh module for some reason. When hovering over `mesh`, it says: "Cannot find 'mesh' in '__init__.py'" I originally had the directory folder named stlExperiments but then someone said you cannot have stl in the name so I changed all instances of "stl" to "st" and no change, so I'm left to assume it's a completely different problem. Can anybody help? I am in the dark. The import code goes as follows:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import numpy as np
from stl import mesh
```

and the error message goes as follows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Riley/PycharmProjects/stExperiments/stCube.py", line 4, in 
>       from stl import mesh
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'mesh'

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem when installing stl with `pip install stl`

Try using `pip install numpy-stl`

It works on my computer (Windows 10)

#### NOTE:

if you are on python 3.x, simply change pip to pip3

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error when running `python3 myScript.py`:

> from stl import mesh
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stl'

## Virtual environment

It was resolved by creating a virtual environment and using it:

```bash
python3 -m venv virtual-environment
source virtual-environment/bin/activate
pip3 install numpy-stl
python3 myScript.py
```